# Implementing Team Foundation Server with a small development team

Tags: version-control, tfs

We have a small 3 developer team that is currently using Subversion for our source control. We expect the team to group to 8 members within the next 6 to 12 months. We are considering changing our source control to either TFS or Mercurial for improved branching. I know TFS is overkill for just branching, but that is the immediate need, and the other features of TFS could aid our team. One of our main concerns with TFS is we've heard that there is a lot of overhead deploying it, especially on a small team. I'm hoping to get some community insight into just how much overhead there may be involved, suggestions to make the process easier, and anything else the community may feel is useful in making the decision to implement.

Comment: Try AccuRev too - its a lot cheaper than TFS, but much easier to set up and work with. Good branching features too.

Comment: What branching / merging features does TFS provide that SVN doesn't?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In my experience, TFS works really well, even for small teams. If your total number of developers is five or less, you can use the relatively affordable Workgroup edition: above that, you'll have to pony up for the real thing, pricing for which is definitely in the 'Enterprise' realm...

The biggest hurdle to starting to use TFS is installing the darn thing: this process seems to be designed for maximum aggravation. (The extent to which the 'designers' of the 2005-to-2008 upgrade 'process' despise their users even manages to go beyond that: fortunately, you'll be able to start with TFS2008 and won't have to worry about upgrading for a while).

If you follow the [instructions](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=FF12844F-398C-4FE9-8B0D-9E84181D9923&displaylang=en) *exactly*, you should manage in 2-3 tries, though, and the hardware requirements aren't as bad as they seem. My 3-developer TFS setup runs quite comfortable on a previous-generation Dell laptop with 4GB of RAM.

One of the big advantages of TFS is the VS integration: this works just really, really well, and shelving and branching are implemented in a more straightforward way than with any other systems I've seen.

The process guidance and support in TFS are a bit less polished, but still quite usable. The pluggable support for several development methodologies is quite nice, and several third-party add-ons (for example for [Scrum](http://www.scrumforteamsystem.com/en/default.aspx)) are available already.

All in all, it definitely won't hurt to try TFS: if you have a MSDN subscription, you probably already have the Workgroup edition as well as a trial of the full version: otherwise, you can [downloaded the latter from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=B0155166-B0A3-436E-AC95-37D7E39A440C&displaylang=en) as well.

**UPDATE, April 12th, 2010:** With the release of [Team Foundation Server 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/premium), the installation and upgrade procedures have improved *a lot*. A new TFS2010 install shouldn't take you more than a few minutes (assuming you already have an instance of SQL Server 2008 up and running) and even an in-place upgrade of my TFS2008 setup proved to be entirely painless.

Comment: I just want to agree with the "maximum aggravation" comment.  The upgrade is indeed ugly.  In our case, we called MS Support and had them complete the upgrade from 2005 to 2008 for us... it took all of 2 days to complete on our relatively small environment.

Comment: The install itself is pretty painful.  On a Server 2008 box, the trouble only really started when trying to apply SP1 for TFS.  The solution in the end was to roll-back and to slipstream the service pack into the main iso....

Comment: Yeah, installation was a real pain! Most important: don't try and use other versions of Windows Server, Windows SQL Server, or anything else which is needed for TFS - just use the one which the docs say to use. Oh, and only use english versions of these. Localized versions of Windows Server are not playing nice with TFS.

Comment: I know this is an old question (2010), but I wanted to point out for anyone coming to this page with the same question now that if you have VS2012 or above, there is a new option for small teams.  Microsoft now allows you to sign up for Team Foundation Services free through Visual Studio Online.  This allows small teams to use TFS source control for free for up to 5 users.  Downside is your code is stored in Microsoft's cloud, upside is there is no install required.  For small teams, this can be a really nice thing, plus you can migrate to a local TFS install at any time.

Answer (score 4):

Setup of TFS is not too complicated, when you *exactly* follow the given guide step by step. We are using it on a small team for about one year now and i don't want to miss it any more.

Especially when you use more than one part of tfs like version control and work item tracking and maybe even teambuild, your team will benefit of the tight integration of the seperate parts.

For example, you can link to workitems when checking in code changes.
Then you run an automated build with teambuild and it will automatically update your workitems with the build number.
So afterwards you can see for example in a bug workitem the buildnumber which contains the bugfix.

We also use the sharepoint wiki for documentation and planning although i'm not the biggest sharepoint fan...

The main point is the great integration into the IDE and for workitem tracking the Teamsystem Web Access which allows you to control at least your workitems over a webinterface.

Answer (score 1):

It's been awhile, but I'm thinking that it takes about a half-day to get setup, plus some time reading the manuals beforehand to make sure you know what you're doing.  Configuration doesn't take too long -- you need to add all of your developers in as licensed users.  Setting up projects is not too hard.  I usually set up AD groups to map on the project roles and add those groups to the appropriate roles.  I set up a new project in about 1/2 hour.

Note: I don't use any of the features of TFS except source control.  If you plan to item tracking, use the project sharepoint site, etc., your mileage will vary quite a bit.  I've found that on our projects (2-3 developers) a wiki works just as well for project management.